# How to abandon part of webpage with Jsoup?

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I am currently using Jsoup to parse a html. The code is quite simple:

```
Document doc = null;
    try{
        doc = Jsoup.connect(link).get();    
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        //System.out.println("Some error occured.");
        textView.setText(e.getMessage());
    }
```

It do gives me the webpage I want, later I can extract the data I need from that webpage with it's getElementsByTag method and so on. However, I only want to use part of the webpage, for example, I wish to abandon everything after < ! -- / foo --> in my webpage. (Actually It's does not have blank between < and !, but I can't type that here.) Is there any way of abandon the webpage after that string and get the new Document with only the part I want? I checked the cookbook, but it seems only process the webpage in it's structure, so I am not quite sure is it OK to do something like string remove. Thanks for your reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html) where HTML is a page HTML. I.e. take HTML first by

```
   Connection connect = Jsoup.connect(url);
   Connection.Response response = connect.execute();
   String html = response.body();
```

then do whatever operations you need (e.g. cut HTML after marker, but add necessary closing HTML tags), then

```
   Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html)
```

Comment: I see, in this case, I shouldn't get the Document object with doc = Jsoup.connect(link).get(); , instead, I should get the webpage first, do whatever I need, then re-parse it to the Document object? I am wondering are there any way to modify the Document object directly, but still really appreciate your help.

Comment: You still can get elements of the document and call 'remove()' on them. For example, put all removable html inside a div or span with special ID and remove it.